# SQL Server - Call stored procedure in a IN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

First of all, is it even possible ?

I have a stored procedure which looks like:

`SELECT this FROM table WHERE this IN (SELECT that FROM another_table WHERE that = @Param)`

I would like to replace `(SELECT that FROM another_table WHERE that = @Param)` by another stored procedure

I am having trouble finding the right syntax to make it work. I tried:

`SELECT this FROM table WHERE this IN (EXEC new_stored_procedure @Param)`

But this doesn't work. Does somebody know the right syntax to do so ?

Thank you for helping

Comment: No, this is not possible. You'd have to execute the stored procedure first, and store the results into a temporary table (or table variable) and then use a `SELECT .. FROM ...` in the `IN` clause

Comment: Does you SP using DML?

Comment: Unfortunetly, it does. Otherwize, i'd use a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary table

```
-- match exact columns with datatype returned from the stored procedure
create table #temp(col1 int, col2 .... ) 

insert into #temp(col1,...)
EXEC new_stored_procedure @Param


SELECT this FROM table WHERE this IN (select col from #temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Table-Valued Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Get10Companies]
(   
 @DepartmentId Int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    SELECT TOP (10) ID from company
            WHERE DepartmentId = @DepartmentId
)


 SELECT * from ( Select * from Get10Companies (1104)) t
```

Comment: I simplified the query, but actually the new_stored_procedure should do an insert, which function can't do.